# How to rename (main) hard disk back to default? And is the disk default really LVG?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, ssd, disk-utility, core-storage

I recently reinstalled OS X, when it asked me to erase the disk I just left it Untitled, since there's no instruction to rename it to whatever on [this Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18869?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US), after restoring with Time Machine the disk name became Untitled, same with the partitioned name, which I easily rename to Macintosh HD.

Here are screenshots of the Untitled HD

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

specs: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) - 256GB

AFAIR the original name has something to do with the capacity and SSD brand. Now I can't remember the original disk name and I don't know how to (safely) rename it,

To add up, I think my old disk is GUID, not LVG, did I do something wrong? **How can I revert back everything to the default state**, I'm quite anal about these things since it might results in problems in the future etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a proper link to the screenshot

Comment: Added proper link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming scheme for non-CoreStorage devices/volumes looks like this:

- (hard-coded) name of the disk device

  - EFI (invisible in non-tweaked Disk Utility)
  - Volume 1 (usually Macintosh HD)
  - Volume 2 (optional)
  - ... (optional further volumes)
  - Recovery HD (invisible)

And the naming scheme for CoreStorage devices/volumes looks like this (a Fusion-disk has an additional invisible EFI partition, an invisible Boot OS X volume and a second invisible Physical Volume):

- name of the Logical Volume Group

  - EFI (invisible)
  - name of Logical Volume 1 (usually Macintosh HD)
  - name of Logical Volume 2 (optional)
  - ... (optional further volumes)
  - name of the Physical Volume (invisible)
  - Recovery HD (invisible)

The names of the Logical Volume Group and the Logical Volumes usually derive from former volume names or is just "Untitled" for Physical Volume(s) but the hard-coded physical device name is rarely used (I have seen it only once, probably the owner renamed it).

**Renaming the Logical Volume Group:**

To rename the Logical Volume Group use:

```
diskutil cs rename lvgUUID|lvgName newName
```

To get the lvgUUID just enter `diskutil cs list`. It's the first UUID listed. Alternatively you may use the Logical Volume Name. I don't know whether this works if you have several equally named LVGs or PVs. Therefore I always prefer the UUID.

To get the previous visible disk device name open "About your Mac" -> System Report -> Hardware -> SATA/SATA Express and search for your device.

**Reverting CoreStorage to non-CoreStorage:**

To revert the CoreStorage **non-destructively** to a traditional non-CoreStorage volume boot to Recovery Mode/Internet Recovery Mode or an OS X thumb drive.

Open Termínal.app and enter:

```
diskutil cs list
```

to get the Logical Volume UUID (usually it's the last listed) and enter:

```
diskutil cs revert lvUUID
```

to convert your CoreStorage device to non-CoreStorage.

Though the command converts CS to non-CS non-destructively it's always a good advice to have a current backup of your main volume.

***You mustn't do this with Fusion drives or you will destroy all your data.***

Comment: Got it, so which is prefered now; CoreStorage or a traditional non-CoreStorage? Also I saw this and this confuses me https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT201723, do I need to make my disk GUID? Or using LVG is the new norm? I could swear my disk looks much like this before: https://i.imgur.com/oO4KTKg.jpg

Comment: @AnotherHay You don't have to GUID your disk because it is already whether you use CS or not. GUID partition table is just a partition table standard replacing older ones. CoreStorage is some kind of LVM (Logical Volume Manager) ~ two layers above. You may use it or not. On a single disk without encryption it's almost useless. But your disk will automatically converted to CS if you enable FileVault.